# White listing effectiveness against SQL Injection

Tags: php, sql, regex, pdo, sql-injection

Let's say I had something like the following:

```
function return_some_info($db, $id){

    if (! preg_match("/^\d{5}$/",$id)) {
      header("Location: safepage.php");
      exit;
    }

    $query="SELECT `column1`, `columns2` FROM `table` WHERE `columnId`=:id ORDER BY `column1` ASC";
    $query_params = array(
        ':id' => $id
    );

    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($query_params);
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $infoArr[]=$row;
    };
    return $infoArr;
}
```

And let's say $id is a dynamic variable that could be changed by a malicious user (normally system generated, but potentially malipulated).  If $id should always be a five digit integer, with the regex and redirect, is there any possible way that injection could ever get past the "whiltelisting" for a five digit integer only.  So for instance if instead of using PDO with paramterized queries, there was:

```
$query="SELECT `column1`, `columns2` FROM `table` WHERE `columnId`=".$id." ORDER BY `column1` ASC";
```

Would that make any difference as far as the potential for SQL injection since the redirect isn't going to let anything that isn't a five digit integer past?  I'm not doing this, suggesting this or considering this (the above query without paramterized queries).  I don't need a bunch of answers talking about the importance of PDO or something similar for stopping SQL injection.  I'm trying to understand in a deeper way the logic of security.  So this question isn't really so much about the SQL injection but about the effectiveness of whitelisting/sanitization in the above manner.

My overall question is this:  Is there anyway that someone injecting extra code into the $id variable would ever get past the regex redirect with something other than a five digit integer?

Further clarification:  Apparently, as hard as I tried, I didn't explain what I wanted.  Let me copy some text from above:

"I'm not doing this, suggesting this or considering this (the above query without paramterized queries).  I don't need a bunch of answers talking about the importance of PDO or something similar for stopping SQL injection.  I'm trying to understand in a deeper way the logic of security."

I'm really looking for the effectiveness of the whitelisting/sensitization regex I've listed.  My curiosity on this goes completely outside of SQL queries but I thought maybe this would be a good example to use.  Apparently not.  Wiktor actually answered my question.  Most everyone else just got worked up about SQL injection (hyped up by Your Common Sense -- the self appointed galaxy expert on the subject).  Any other replies to my real question would be appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: Well, you regex will also accept `12345\n`.

Comment: there's many types of injection. using placeholders as you only protects against SOME forms of it. it can't prevent someone from sending a malicious-but-otherwise-acceptable value in the first place. e.g. if record 12345 belongs to user X, then if user Y sends that, your query would still allow it to be viewed.

Comment: Why is everyone always looking for tricks to avoid prepared queries as the way to prevent SQL injection?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Not without the `m` regex modifier.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, that's completely baffling to me. With ORMs available like Laravel's Fluent/Eloquent it's not even additional code complexity to deal with.

Comment: @Barmar: Even without `/m` modifier. But that is not that point here. I just commented on the question if anything other than 5 digits can be accepted with this regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I just learned something new -- that's an unusual behavior of PHP regexp, you have to use the `D` modifier to disable it.

Comment: @Barmar: Yes, or just use `\z`.

Comment: So your real question is whether your regex matches what you think it does and/or how to validate a 5 digit integer? Then what's the whole dance and song about general security practices and SQL injection in particular? Of course, if your code doesn't do what you think it does, the security implications are unknown and potentially disastrous.

Comment: @deceze, Yes.  That is my real question as stated in my original post.  "Of course, if your code doesn't do what you think it does, the security implications are unknown and potentially disastrous."  Isn't that self evident?  So what would I do in that situation?  Maybe post a question on stackoverflow to see what others thought?  Hence, this question?

Comment: "So what would I do in that situation?" @Dang, you could always the industry-standard, battle-tested approach of parameterized queries.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this question is quite ambiguous and it's hard to tell what you're actually asking. But at least I can answer one of the questions:

> So this question is ... about the effectiveness of whitelisting/sanitization in the above manner.

**It's apparently ineffective,** as it will require special attention for each particular variable. Here you need an integer and there you need a boolean, and somewhere you need a string. And in time you will need to change an integer for a string. And so on.

Why bother yourself with all these matters? Why not to learn how to use PDO prepared statements instead? With PDO you can treat all the parameters the same way - just by sending them to the query separately:

```
function return_some_info($db, $id) {

    $query = "SELECT column1, columns2 FROM table WHERE columnId= ? ORDER BY column1";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute([$id]);
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

Look, with proper usage it takes less writing than your approach and works with any data the same way.

**The logic of security** is extremely simple: **the database should be doing it for you.** And this is true for any other medium/destination. Manual sanitization should be avoided in favor of automated formatting.

With your manual formatting/sanitization, a developer become responsible for the safety. And I can assure you - it's [the most unreliable link in the chain](https://phpdelusions.net/sql_injection#manual). Proper formatting have to be done by the DB driver - so PDO does. That's why you should always use binding.

While whitelisting is recommended when you cannot use binding - for the field names, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes... ***if***

1. your whitelist code is correct **and**
2. your whitelist code is bug free **and**
3. you know exactly how all possible values will be parsed and treated in all possible situations **and**
4. you have not forgotten any specific special case which might slip through

... then just *maybe* a whitelist approach can be secure.

The point is that this is a lot if ***ifs***, and you'll change your code in the future and you'll make mistakes in the future and you'll forget to validate something somewhere somehow and some unsanitized values *will* slip through one day...

The big great advantage of a prepared statement API is that **you cannot break it.** Using value placeholders and passing values separately and doing this all the way to the database using the native prepared statement API **cannot break** no matter how stressed or drunk or forgetful or stupid you were when you wrote that code.

Yes, it's physically possible to secure database queries in alternative ways, but it's **humanly much much harder** and hence not worth bothering with.

Comment: So what if you were doing something completely outside of an SQL query?  And there were no API?  Then you need to know if your code is correct and bug free and how all possible values will be parsed and that I haven't forgotten any specific case.  Hence, the question to others to verify those things.  As mentioned above this is not an SQL injection question, this a deeper security logic question.

Comment: @Dang what is your question anyway? Is it "should I use whitelisting if there is no API for the automated formatting"? *Yes, you should.* Did you really considered any other answer? But as long as there is any API, you should be using it instead of manual formatting. That's all the sacred security logic you are looking for.

Comment: @Dang This *is* specially about SQL queries. SQL is a complex mini-language (not that mini actually), and you're trying to programmatically write source code for that language. This is conceptually something very complex which must be approached with appropriate care and diligence, but in practice never is. Yes it's possible, but parameter binding is so much less error prone since it avoids the entire approach. If you were trying the same thing in any other language (e.g. programmatically produce PHP code) the issue would be the same. **But we're talking specifically about SQL here.**

Comment: @deceze, Obviously you are talking specifically about SQL, but you didn't really read my post.  From my post, " So this question isn't really so much about the SQL injection but about the effectiveness of whitelisting/sanitization in the above manner."  Again, there is a fury of emotion about SQL Injection and apparently I should not have used it in my example (my bad).  Maybe my title and tag attracted only DBAs and web developers who never do custom coding outside of frameworks.

Comment: @Dang "White listing effectiveness against SQL injection"... Well, yeah, that may have tainted your question just a little bit. But be that as it may, security is always about specifics. Whitelisting **in general** is obviously a tried and true approach. Against SQL injections in particular it's *possible but still wrongheaded*, and in your code in very particular there may be holes. What are you really asking? And stop with the passive aggressiveness please.

Comment: @YourCommonSense  I've read many of your answers on other posts, even gone to your site and apparently you know more than anyone on the planet about SQL injection.  Kudos to that.  "Did you really considered any other answer?"  Apparently I must have, or I wouldn't have asked the question.  Obviously Wiktor understood my question and gave me a reasonable and insightful answer.

Comment: @Dang he gave you an answer for a very narrow topic, very special case, but by no means for the general topic on the security logic. If particular regexp was all what you were asking for, then I've been wrong with my answer. I just misunderstood your question.

Comment: @deceze, "What are you really asking?"  From my post, " Is there anyway that someone injecting extra code into the $id variable would ever get past the regex redirect with something other than a five digit integer?"  That is what I'm really asking.  I don't know how else to describe it.  Wiktor understood my post and gave me one answer to my question.  I'm looking for others if there are any.  Apologies if it wasn't explained well enough.

Comment: @Dang What you posted is a very leading question. If that's the only detail you want to ask about, then just ask that! Going on and on about SQL and PDO and whitelisting and whatnot really distracts from that kernel. Wiktor just commented one example in which the whole approach already shows weaknesses; I'm not sure he understood your question anymore than anyone else.