# Can anyone hack $id = (int) $_REQUEST['edit_id']; with SQL injection?

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

I have code that looks like:

```
$id = (int) $_REQUEST['edit_id'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dis WHERE dis_id = $id ");
```

Can anyone do SQL injection in this code like I am using `(int)` to filter the raw data? If so, how can it be hacked and how can the hack be prevented?

Comment: [Don't use mysql_* extension](http://www.php.net/en/mysql_query) as it is deprecated. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead. And their prepared statements.

Comment: Hint: What happens if the `edit_id` is `cheesesandwich`? `123cheesesandwich`? `-12345`? `6.02e23`? `-1/12`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35297271/white-listing-effectiveness-against-sql-injection#comment58305650_35297271

Comment: @zwol, PHP will make that `0` or any other valid integer.

Comment: @BartFriederichs It was a rhetorical question meant to get the OP thinking along the right lines, but - *all* of the things I listed get mapped to zero?

Comment: @zwol, no, I changed my comment. Not always `0`, but always a valid integer.

Comment: @BartFriederichs Also, I'm not *just* talking about the `(int)` cast.  The database could behave surprisingly if given `SELECT * FROM dis WHERE dis_id = -234` for instance.  (I don't know if it *would*, but it's Another Thing To Worry About.)

Comment: @zwol. No. Databases are pretty deterministic in nature. They will just find no record.

Comment: Do NOT use `mysql_*` it has been removed and it will not work anymore, use `PDO` or `mysqli_*` instead.

Comment: @BartFriederichs I think we're talking past each other.  I'm posing rhetorical questions in order to teach the OP *how to think about the problem*.  The actual answers to the questions are somewhat beside the point.

Answer (score 6):

This on itself won't hurt and this specific case will not lead to SQL injection.

**However**, teach yourself to *always* use prepared statements, to train your muscle memory and not take "shortcuts".

Comment: ok thanks and can anyone hack $user_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['user_name']);
 $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']);

Comment: Stop taking shortcuts. Use prepared statements. Always.

Comment: @AshutoshPandey - If you're using a properly hashed password, then you should never need to even try using `mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']);` - please don't tell me that you're storing passwords in plaintext

Comment: @MarkBaker: But the user may not have passed a properly hashed password, so the escaping is necessary for general security, even if it will not do anything when the system is not being hacked.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - A user shouldn't be passing a hashed password; they should be passing a password for validation, and password validation functions should not care about any specific characters in the password... I re-iterate, there is no need (and you shouldn't) escape a password

Answer (score 0):

There’s nothing wrong with it, assuming there’s no way way to break the int filter. However, things break all the time (in this case there’s little to worry about). But I agree with the previous answer: use prepared statements so sanitization/validation is built in.

I usually don’t trust a single layer of security when I can make sure my data is sanitized/validated with a line or 2. I made a trait that checks for expected input, and reuse it from project to project if I’m patching something without prepared statements.

Answer (score -1):

I usually create a bunch of custom php sanitisation scripts for my applications to sanitise incoming data and run these against the data just for peace of mind. For example...

```
function SanitiseIntegerData($data) {

    if ( preg_match("/[^\d]/", $data ) == TRUE ) { //If data contains characters apart from integers
        echo("ERROR: Invalid GET data");
        $_SESSION = array();
        session_destroy();
        session_unset();

        echo "<script>window.location='index.php'</script>";
    }else{
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i update or insert new record using sql injection with php can i have an example

Comment: `$id = SanitiseIntegerData($_REQUEST['edit_id']); $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM dis WHERE dis_id = $id ");`